# Diferenciar Enter de Shift Enter em um textarea, obtendo o valor via javascript

Tags: javascript, ascii, textarea

Tenho um `textarea` fora de um formulário:

```
<textarea name="textoOriginal">
```

Dentro dessa `textarea`, posso digitar um texto, e <kbd>ENTER</kbd> ou <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>ENTER</kbd> para quebra de linha. Quando pego o valor do elemento, preciso diferenciar o que foi <kbd>ENTER</kbd> e o que foi <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>ENTER</kbd>, porém recebo todos com o código ASCII 10

Teste que fiz:

Html:

```
<textarea class="form-control" name="textoOriginal" rows="15"></textarea>
```

Javascript:

```
document.querySelector('textarea[name="textoOriginal"').value.split('')
.forEach( function (value) {
             console.log(value + ' corresponde a:'+value.charCodeAt(0));
});
```

Comment: Curiosidade: qual seria a aplicação disso?

Comment: O html interno gerado para os dois casos é o mesmo, assim como o efeito visual. Porquê diferenciar em código?

Comment: Você pode realizar isto utilizando os eventos:
    onkeydown
    onkeypress
    onkeyup

Answer (score 1):

Segue código para conseguir o resultado desejado:

```js
function getCaret(el) { 
  if (el.selectionStart) { 
    return el.selectionStart; 
  } else if (document.selection) { 
    el.focus(); 

    var r = document.selection.createRange(); 
    if (r == null) { 
      return 0; 
    } 

    var re = el.createTextRange(), 
        rc = re.duplicate(); 
    re.moveToBookmark(r.getBookmark()); 
    rc.setEndPoint('EndToStart', re); 

    return rc.text.length; 
  }  
  return 0; 
}

$('textarea').keyup(function (event) {
       if (event.keyCode == 13 && event.shiftKey) {
           var content = this.value;
           var caret = getCaret(this);
           this.value = content.substring(0,caret)+"\n"+content.substring(caret,content.length-1);
           event.stopPropagation();
           
      }else if(event.keyCode == 13)
      {
          $('form').submit();
      }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form><textarea></textarea></form>
```

Postei aqui pra te ajudar, mas o crédito é todo do cara que respondeu essa pergunta: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6014702

PS: Tentando num HTML local, mesmo sem esse código o textarea estava pulando a linha sem submeter o formulário, não consegui entender porque...

Comment: Muito bom, obrigado.